# Issue with custom rails engine db:migrate rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In rails 3.1 you can use the awesome rake task to copy in migrations as seen below from your engine.

`rake my_engine:install:migrations`

This normally works perfectly if i direct my Gemfile to the git repository or via :path.

However, if i just use the ruby gem directly
`gem 'spud_admin'`
my rake task disappears
Any ideas why this rake task disappears?

Comment: is your task listed in "bundle exec rake -T"? Have you tried "bundle exec rake my_engine:install:migrations"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved. It had something to do with how jeweler had structured the gem environment. Switching to bundler and using rails plugin new seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had a similar problem and managed to solve it thanks to jipiboily's comment. I have an engine called 'myEngine2' so I tried to call it like that:

> rake myEngine2:install:migrations

but this failed. I than typed

> bundle exec rake -T

there was a line:

> rake my_engine2_engine:install:migrations  # Copy migrations from
>   my_engine2_engine to application

I gave it a shot and it worked. Maybe it's the same problem in your case?

Comment: Sorry tried bundle exec and it is still not showing up. Thanks for the suggestion though, this is really odd.